# SumIf formula in Excel with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

Apologies for the seemingly basic Excel question - I have tried Google but can't quite find anything about this!

All I want to do is do a sum of a column based if the corresponding column before that fits into certain criteria.

For example, if I have:

```
    Column A   Column B
    YY            20
    ZZ            4
    TT            8
    UU            15
```

In a seperate cell, I want to sum up Column B where Column A is YY AND TT

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
 =SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{"YY","TT"},B:B))
```

Comment: Wow, I was going to do `=IF(OR(A1="YY",A1="TT"),B1,0)` in column C and sum the C column, but this is *much* nicer.  +1